# Designing a Way for Process to Communicate with Kernel

Tags: design-patterns, c++, operating-systems

I've got a project that is sort of a virtual operating system.

In this project, the `Kernel` class is responsible for creating `Process` classes. The process class consists of `Thread` classes and the `Thread` class will consist of a `CPU` class. The `CPU` class is actually a `CPU` emulator and the `Thread` is therefore an "emulated" thread. So when the `CPU` class encounters an interrupt instruction, it needs to be handled by the kernel because it is usually a system call. The `Kernel` class cannot actually see the `CPU` class directly, it is embedded in the `Thread` class, which is embedded in the `Process` class.

The approach I'm using now uses a `InterruptHandler` class, which handles the system calls and breakpoints. Here's what the code looks like.

```cpp
class CPU final {
  std::shared_ptr<MemoryBus> memoryBus;
  std::shared_ptr<InterruptHandler> interruptHandler;
  std::uint32_t regs[32];
public:
  void Run(unsigned int steps) {
    for (decltype(steps) i = 0; i < steps; i++)
      RunInst();
  }
protected:
  // This function will call the interrupt
  // handler if it encounters an interrupt instruction.
  void RunInst();
};

class Thread final {
  std::shared_ptr<CPU> cpu;
  std::shared_ptr<InterruptHandler> interruptHandler;
public:
  Thread() : cpu(new CPU) {
  }
  void Run(unsigned int steps) {
    cpu->Run(steps);
  }
};

class Process final {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Threads>> threads;
  std::shared_ptr<MemoryMap> memoryMap;
  std::shared_ptr<InterruptHandler> interruptHandler;
public:
  void Run(unsigned int steps) {
    for (auto &t : threads)
      t->Run(steps);
  }
};

class InterruptHandler {
  std::shared_ptr<FS> fs;
public:
  void HandleInterrupt(CPU &cpu, int interrupt_type);
  void HandleSyscall(CPU &cpu, int syscall_type);
  void HandleWrite(CPU &cpu, int fd, const void *buf, unsigned int len);
  // More system calls follow
};

class Kernel final {
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Process>> processes;
  std::vector<InterruptHandler> interruptHandler;
public:
  void Run(unsigned int steps) {
    for (auto &p : processes)
      p->Run(steps);
  }
  void AddProcess(const std::string &path) {
    // opens process, assigns interrupt handler
    processes.emplace_back(process);
  }
};
```

The problem here is that the interrupt handler class has to be passed to just about every sub class of the `Process` class, including the `Process` class. Also, the `InterruptClass` seems like it's going to end up containing a lot of the same data as the `Kernel` class. I don't like this because I feel like it violates the principle of "don't repeat yourself."

I know there's a better way of designing this but I haven't really figured it out yet. Is the Proxy design pattern applicable to this scenario? What about using signals and slots, similar to Qt and also described [here](http://simmesimme.github.io/tutorials/2015/09/20/signal-slot)?

I've left out the URL of this project, because I don't want to come off as self promoting. If the code I provided is too incomplete, I'll reference files in the project for more info.

Comment: _"The Kernel class cannot actually see the CPU class directly, ..."_ - this is the opposite of how you'd expect an OS to actually work. The kernel is responsible for telling each CPU what thread (userspace or otherwise) to run, and for handling interrupts. You're missing the whole scheduler layer.

Comment: @useless I think *CPU* is a **very** misleading term to use here. From what i understood it's more an execution environment of a (byte code interpreting) virtual machine. The "CPU" needs the kernel to perform important operations here.

Comment: @DanielJour you're right, CPU is kind of misleading. I believe Interpreter might be a better name.

Comment: @useless are you saying I shouldn't use the whole process, thread, CPU hierarchy?

Comment: And yet, using a scheduler the way a real OS does will break the problematic dependency chain up nicely. The kernel tells a "CPU" which "thread" to run, instead of asking a thread to execute itself on a CPU and also tunnel interrupt state.

Comment: @Useless alright, I'll give that a shot. I can see how it would be easier. I'm still not sure how quite sure how the kernel will receive the system calls but I think that would probably make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite obvious that what I'm trying to do here is a design error.

With the dependency graph between the kernel and the CPU/Interpreter class, it is quite obvious that they shouldn't be interacting the way I'm trying to get them to interact. There are two solutions, I've realized, to handle software interrupts from the CPU.

**Solution One:**

Break up the dependency between the kernel and the CPU/Interpreter. I could have declared the CPU/Interpreter classes as the topmost class in the design. The CPU/Interpreter emulates the system and the kernel is written in the byte code that the CPU/Interpreter emulates. This is similar to the way systems run normally.

**Solution Two:**

Instead of using CPU interrupt instructions to implement system calls (the way they are usually done), I could use memory mapped input/output. I've already implemented a `MemoryMap` class made up of abstract `MemorySection` class instances. The only current implementation of the `MemorySection` is just a flat memory section. I could derive the `MemorySection` class to a memory mapped file system interface, memory allocation interface, etc..

I ended up going with solution two, because it doesn't require hardly any rewriting of the project.

Answer (score 0):

CPU/Interpreters shouldn't belong to Threads/Processes but to Kernel. They are resources that get allocated by the kernel at thread request.